# Xamarin Forms ListView Entry Field Transfer

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm building an app that needs the Entry field a Button and a ListView, so when I type something in the entry field and click the button, the field entered passes to the List View.
Does anyone have an example that I can rely on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/samples-all/

Answer (score 0):

> so when I type something in the entry field and click the button, the field entered passes to the List View.

First , you can refer to [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding#data-binding) to create a ListView with Data binding.Then adding Button and Entry to layout,last you can deal with adding data by button click event.

The **employee** class:

```
public class Employee{
    public string DisplayName {get; set;}
}
```

The **DataModel** Class:

```
public class DataModel 
{

    public ObservableCollection<Employee> employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();

    public DataModel()
    {
        employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Rob Finnerty" });
        employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Bill Wrestler" });
        employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Dr. Geri-Beth Hooper" });
        employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Dr. Keith Joyce-Purdy" });
        employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Sheri Spruce" });
        employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = "Burt Indybrick" });
    }
}
```

The following snippet demonstrates a `ListView` bound to a list of employees,adding `Button` and `Entry`.When clicking button,text from `Entry` will add to `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App1"
             x:Class="App1.MainPage">

    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Gray">
        <!-- Place new controls here -->

        <Entry x:Name="EntryText" Placeholder="input"/>

        <Button Text="click me" 
                HorizontalOptions="Center"
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                Clicked="OnButtonClicked"/>

        <ListView x:Name="EmployeeView">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Finally `ContentPage` will deal with Click Event:

```
DataModel dataModel;
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataModel = new DataModel();
    EmployeeView.ItemsSource = dataModel.employees;
}

void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("click me");
    dataModel.employees.Add(new Employee { DisplayName = EntryText.Text });
}
```

Comment: Hi Junior, that's exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Glad to hear that be helpful! Remember to mark the answer,then this question will be closed. ^.^